# Is there different methods to save keras DNN model?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, model, neural-network

I'm saving keras DNN model as a '.h5' file, Can you tell me, what all are the other methods used to save keras model. Based on the performance let me know those files.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save/load either JSON or YAML described h5.

**JSON**

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
```

**YAML**

```
model_yaml = model.to_yaml()
with open("model.yaml", "w") as yaml_file:
    yaml_file.write(model_yaml)
```

Since these require extra formatting steps, I expect you'll get the best performance from the standard `model.save_weights`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you know any other file type instead of json/yaml/h5/hdf5 ?

Comment: .h5 is not 'binary format python data", its HDF5. See https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/whatishdf5.html